# Unable to get token from tableau server

Tags: tableau-api

I am following below link to integrate tableau report on web application(asp .net mvc),

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_webrequ.htm

Code :

```
            var uri = "http://<server ip>:8000/trusted";
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("username ", "<user>");
            parameters.Add("target_site", "<site>");
            var bodyParameters = new ArrayList();
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                bodyParameters.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(parameter.Value))));
            }
            string requestBody = String.Join("&", bodyParameters.ToArray());
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            try
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(requestBody);
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    String body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string str = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
```

My machine is registered as trusted host on tableau server, still i am getting -1 when i request for token.

Comment: There could be many reasons for getting the -1 including:
* Incorrect configuration
* Invalid user
* Poorly formed http request
* etc
Did you check your server logs?  They are usually the best place to see the actual error why the server returned -1.  It also looks like you found the right docs but were you successful with [testing auth](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_testing.htm)?

Comment: @tagyoureit : I was looking at path C:\ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\data\tabsvc\vizqlserver\Logs.   Which log to be checked, in this scenario.

Comment: That should be the right log.  You might need to increase logging level.  See https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.5/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trouble.htm.